# xcode static library built from workspace: make symbols not Undefined

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating an iOS static library, using cocoa pods, including AFNetworking. I'm building from a workspace, the standard cocoa pods way. I want the output library to contain everything from AFNetworking, so I included libAFNetworking.a in the Link Binary With Libraries step for the target (although the library names are in red?). Anyway, I cannot successfully use the resulting library in another project - I get undefined symbols on, for instance, `_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

If I run

```
nm -g libMyLibraryBlahBlah.a | grep _AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

I get

```
                     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
    0000000000008760 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
    0000000000008d30 S _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager._baseURL
    etc
```

So `_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is both a symbol and Undefined? How do I make it NOT Undefined?